# save project as .JPG by maximum quality

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have done project in Windows Phone 8, download from internet .JPG file and save project as .JPG file by this function.

```
    public void Save( string filename)
    {    
        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
        tt.X = -rect1.Margin.Left;
        tt.Y = -rect1.Margin.Top;

        // CompositeTransform cpt = new CompositeTransform();//{ScaleY=
        // cpt.ScaleX = pic_width / rect1.Width;
        // cpt.ScaleY = pic_height / rect1.Height;            

        WriteableBitmap writeBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)rect1.Width, (int)rect1.Height);
        writeBmp.Render(grid2, tt);
        writeBmp.Invalidate();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        writeBmp.SaveJpeg(ms, writeBmp.PixelWidth,writeBmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

        ms.Position = 0;
        MediaLibrary mediaLib = new MediaLibrary();
        mediaLib.SavePicture(filename, ms);          
    }
```

But the quality of obtained(by my project) is worse than the original(from internet). how can I save by maximal quality, without a decline in the quality.

Answer (score 1):

`.JPG`s (Joint-Photographic-Experts-Group) aren't very good quality in general, even max-quality won't replicate the original (which is probably of a different, higher-quality format).

I'd suggest saving it as a `.PNG` (Portable-Network-Graphics) there much better quality and support transparency.

[See here for saving .PNGs to IsolatedStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359448/saving-png-image-to-isolated-storage-for-wp7)

Comment: OK, but there isn't  PngEncoder class in Windows Phone 8, I can't find the namespace to add it in usings :(