# How save png and gif images on Windows Phone 8 in "Saved Pictures"?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gif

I need save **png** and **gif** images on Windows Phone 8 in "**Saved Pictures**".
I use MediaLibrary, but the image is saved in **jpg** format.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359448/saving-png-image-to-isolated-storage-for-wp7

Comment: Link to the image is stored in IsolatedStorage, and I need to "Saved Pictures" ...

Comment: Look at Cimbalino toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone does not allow to save .png and .gif image. It will automatically save it as .jpg. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: But some programs retain gif and PNG images

Comment: No, that must be done by using storyboard and animation by using sequence of images.because windows phone not allow users to store images in png or gif format through application.

Comment: Nokia Cinemagraph  makes export to gif http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-cinemagraph/594477c0-e991-4ed4-8be4-466055670e69

Comment: @Flash2048 The platform does not provide native saving as png or gif, put there are other libraries out there that can provide this for you.